# Tables of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Compare the multiplication tables of: $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$:

For $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

[image]

For $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$:
[image]

I also have found a proof that they are isomorphic to each other and that they both have order 6.

I don't know if this interpretation is correct or enough.

Comment: Which interpretation?

Comment: The group operations are additive.

Comment: but then why is a multiplication table required?

Comment: Because it is a ring, not only an additive group.

Comment: Multiplication here refers to the group operation (which is commonly written in a multiplicative manner for general groups), it is a bit of an unfortunate naming collision since the group operation in this case is addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every group has an operation. For some groups this operation also has a 'real world' interpretation (like addition, or composition of functions, or actual multiplication of numbers) but the charm of group theory is that by zooming out all these seemingly different real world operations are examples of the same thing: a group operation.

Now some people will call the operation in any abstract group 'multiplication' regardless of if that matches the real world application or not. The person who gave you this assignment is one of those: the 'multiplication table' should better be called 'operation table'.

You have to forget about what else you know about these groups besides them being groups and just make the table for the group operation.

What Shaun tries to tell you in the other answer (and comments) is that in these cases the group operation is what in the real world would be called addition. So in these particular cases the table we want is the 'addition table'.

But Shaun and I know that that is what is wanted for two reasons: calling such a table a 'multiplication table' is quite common (even if Cayley table is a better because more neutral word) and 2) addition is the only 'natural', 'pre-existing' operation on these sets that makes them into a group. It is true that there is multiplication too, but looking at these sets with multiplication as a the operation wont make them into a group.

(It is a nice, but unrelated, exercise to check what part of the definition of group is violated when using multiplication as the operation.)

Answer (score 2):

Group Cayley tables satisfy the [Latin square property](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_has_Latin_Square_Property). Your tables do not. The reason: you used multiplication instead of addition.

Comment: so even when a multiplication table is required i still would have to do addition?

Comment: If you're talking about these *groups*, @Annelisa, then yes.

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain me also the logic behind it? I know that these are groups under addition and not under multiplication but what is the sense of the multiplication table if we need the addition table?

Comment: They're called "Cayley tables", not multiplication tables; I assume that's what you mean, @Annalisa, since you used the [tag:cayley-table] tag.

Comment: Would it make a difference if I remove the tag? I am just asked to compare the multiplication tables of the following groups. That's it.

Comment: I removed the tag, it was my mistake maybe to have it, since I am not explicitly asked to have a Cayley table.

Comment: No, @Annalisa; the operation, if considered as a group, is *still addition* and cannot be multiplication.

Comment: Every group has an operation. For some groups this operation also has a 'real world' interpretation (like addition, or composition of functions, or actual multiplication of numbers) but the charm of group theory is that by zooming out all these seemingly different real world operations are examples of the same thing a group operation. Now some people will call the operation in any abstract group 'multiplication' regardless of if that matches the real world application or not. The person who gave you this job is one of those: the 'multiplication table' should better be called 'operation table'

Comment: You have to forget about what else you know about these groups besides them being groups and just make the table for the group operation

Comment: What Shaun tries to tell you is that in these cases the group operation is what in the real world would be called addition. So in these particular cases the table we want is the 'addition table'. But Shaun and I know that that is what is wanted for two reasons: calling such a table a 'multiplication table' is quite common (even if Cayley table is a better because more neutral word) and 2) addition is the only operation that makes these groups into a group. It is true that there is multiplication too, but looking at these sets with multiplication as a the operation wont make them int a group

Comment: @Vincent thank you, it was very insightful. Which means I only have to do the normal addition table with the addition of components in the first and normal addition modulo 6 in the second.

Comment: (it is a nice, but unrelated, excercise to check what part of the definition of group is violated when using multiplication as the operation)

Comment: @Annalisa yes that is correct

Comment: And then the second part: see that they are isomorphic (which you already did for the other tables) is also desirable here. I am pretty sure that that is what the makers of the assignment hoped for you to find even if they didn't want to say it aloud to avoid spoilers

Comment: @Vincent I would really recommend you write your comment as an answer. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Alright. I'll use copy and paste to do it...